# Different ways to write a function determining if a value is a tuple

Tags: swift, tuples

What are the different ways to create a function to determine if something is a tuple in Swift 3? I am looking for different variations, big or small.

Here is one way I came up with:

```
func isTuple(value: Any) -> Bool {
    if let style = Mirror(reflecting: value).displayStyle, style == .tuple {
        return true
    }

    return false
}

print(isTuple(value: 2))  // false
print(isTuple(value: ()))  // true
```

Comment: Reflection seems like the tool fit for the task for such a job. Note that you could condense the full body of `isTuple` above to `return Mirror(reflecting: value).displayStyle.map { $0 == .tuple } ?? false`.

Comment: Or just `return Mirror(reflecting: value).displayStyle == .tuple` :)

Comment: But really, I'm not entirely sure what you're expecting from an answer. You've found a good solution, and Swift's introspection abilities are fairly limited. "What are other ways to do X?" kind of questions really aren't a good fit for SO as they're too open-ended.

Comment: @Hamish ah, I've gotten so used to the removal of the _pure comparison_ operators between optionals that I forgot that we may still test for equality (`func ==<T : Equatable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool`), thanks :)

Comment: @Hamish Your solution won't work because displayStyle is an Optional.  I found a solution, but am curious of alternatives. I also don't think this is open ended - in fact, the # of possible ways should be bounded.

Comment: @Boon As dfri points out, the standard library defines a `==` overload for optionals, so it should work (did you try it?). And while the number of *reasonable* ways of achieving this (there are endless unreasonable ways of doing it) may be bounded, this bound isn't defined by the question itself, making it too broad.

Comment: @Hamish I tried - it didn't work. Unreasonable ways will be voted down. Again, I don't think the bound needs to be defined here - the nature of the problem (determine tuple) should present the constraint automatically.

Comment: @Boon What error did you get? What version of Swift are you using? Compiles fine for me in both Swift 3.0.2 and 3.1.

Comment: @Hamish My apology - I must have messed up somewhere when I first tried you solution before posting. Could you post as an answer so I can upvote?

Comment: @dfri What do you mean by removal of pure comparison operators between optionals?

Comment: @Boon in Swift 3, the evolution proposal [_SE-0121: Remove Optional Comparison Operators_](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md) the operators from `Comparable` (`<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`) where removed for comparison between optionals (even if the wrapped type itself conforms to `Comparable`). See the linked evolution proposal for details.